# If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$ has radius convergence $ R > 0$. if $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$ $|z-z_o| < R$ show that $a_0 = a_1 = ... =0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$ has a radius of convergence $R > 0$ and if $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$ $|z-z_o| < R$ show that $a_0 = a_1 = ... =0$.

**Proof Attempt:**

If it has a radius of convergence $R > 0$ then I know $\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| > 0$.

Pick $z^*$ to be in the radius of convergence, then we know that :

$$ 0 = a_0 + a_1(z^*-z_0) + ...+a_n(z^*-z_0)^n + ...$$

Which means that for some $a_i \rightarrow 0 \leq i \leq n$ we can write:

$$a_i = (z^* - z_0)^{-i} (-a_0 - a_1(z^* - z_0) - ...-a_{i+1}(z^* - z_0)^{i+1} -....-a_n(z^*-z_0)^n) + ....$$

$$a_{i+1} = (z^* - z_0)^{-(i+1)} (-a_0 - a_1(z^* - z_0) - ...-a_{i+2}(z^* - z_0)^{(i+2} -....-a_n(z^*-z_0)^n). + ...$$

I want to setup now a contradiction, by using the fact that  as $i \rightarrow 0$ then $  | a_{i+1}/a_i | > 0 $:

$$ \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}| \frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i} |  = (z^* - z_0)^{-1}\frac{(-a_0 - a_1(z^* - z_0) - ...-a_{i+2}(z^* - z_0)^{i+2} -....-a_n(z^*-z_0)^n). + ...)}{(-a_0 - a_1(z^* - z_0) - ...-a_{i+1}(z^* - z_0)^{i+1} -....-a_n(z^*-z_0)^n) + ....)} $$

and I am having troubles concluding anything from this ... can someone suggest maybe another way?

**Attempt II**

I am attempting a solution based on $f(z) = f'(z) = ... = f^k(z) = 0$

$$(1) \ a_0 + a_1(z-z_0) + a_2(z-z_0)^2 + a_3(z-z_0)^3 + ... = 0 $$
$$(2) \ a_1 + 2a_2(z-z_0) + 3a_3(z-z_0)^2 + ... = 0 $$
$$ (3) \ 2a_2 + 3\times 2a_3(z-z_0) + ... = 0 $$

Take $(2) \times (z-z_0)$:

$$(2) \ a_1(z-z_0) + 2a_2(z-z_0)^2 + 3a_3(z-z_0)^3 + ... = 0 $$

Subtract it from (1)?

$$a_0 - [a_2(z-z)^2 + 2a_3(z-z_0)^3 + ... ] = 0 $$

Not sure where to go with this...

Comment: Power series can be differentiated term by term (any number of times). Just look at $f(0), f'(0), f''(0),...$.

Comment: I  attempted with this strategy (in the original question....) having troubles seeing how to conclude $a_0 = a_1 = ...$ from this...

Comment: There is a formula relating the $a_n$ with the $n$th derivative.

Comment: Your formula for $1/R$ in your first attempt is wrong, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**  $f^{(n)}(z_0)=n!\cdot a_n$.

Or, since $\lvert z-z_0\rvert \lt R$ has an accumulation point,  you can use the *identity theorem*.
The power series is unique.